# OneToMany twig filter

Tags: symfony, twig, twig-filter

I have an one article and more comments. I want to display only comments that are not marked as 'Deleted'.
I have tried something like this, but I know that's not correct.

```
{% for comment in article.comments([{delete: false}])|slice(0, 5) %}
    // ...
{% endfor %}
```

I'm trying to take 5 comments that are not marked as 'deleted'. How can I do it?

Comment: which is the result with that code??

Comment: Try writing filtering logic in new method in the `Article` and then slice those results.

Comment: @JuanI.MoralesPestana no error thrown, nothing changed. (I deleted cache as well).

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
{% for comment in article.comments|slice(0, 5) if not comment.deleted %}
    // ...
{% endfor %}
```

But i am afraid that it may result in less than 5 comments because it will slices first before testing if the comment is not deleted.

**Instead you could better write a custom method** in your articleRepository that delivers only comments that are not deleted.

```
# src/AppBundle/Repository/ArticleRepository.php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

class ArticleRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function getAllWithoutDeletedComments()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
            'SELECT a FROM AppBundle:Article a
            JOIN a.comments c WITH c.deleted=0'
        )   ->getResult();
    }
}
```

And call it from your controller:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$articles = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Article')->getAllWithoutDeletedComments();
```

**Or alternatively add a method to your entity** that filters the comments that are not deleted

```
public function getActiveComments($limit = 5)
{
    $counter = 0;
    $activeComments = [];

    foreach($this->comments as $comment) 
    {
        if(!$comment->getDeleted())
        {
            $activeComments[] = $comment;

            if(++$counter == $limit)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $activeComments;
}
```

and of course call this in Twig:

```
{% for comment in article.activeComments() %}
    // ...
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate your support, but I found another solution, and, in my opinion looks better.

In the `Article` entity I have create a new method:

```
public function getAvailableComments()
{
    return $this->getComments()->filter(function(Comment $comment) {
        return !$comment->isDeleted();
    });
}
```

This function returns only non-deleted comments. (Source: https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/collections/easy-collection-filtering)

Note: Twig is the same as in question.

Comment: I agree with you @DarkBee, but for what I have its enough :)